# Verify JWT token expiration in middleware of NextJS 14

Tags: javascript, next.js, jwt, authorization

I'm implementing an authentication & authorization app with JWT, NextJS & MongoDB

Here I can successfully do authentication like `/signup` & `/signin`. During `/signin` I've creating an JWT token & set it's expires time for 1m (for testing)

- Now After `/signin` I can visit `/admin` `/profile` & can fetch `/profile` data.
- After 1m expires the `/profile` data can't be fetched as expected

#### Problem

Although the token expires but still I can visit all route cause the token is already exist in `cookies` but not valid expire token.

- I've create below middleware. Here if I try to

> ...  && (!token || JSON.parse(token).expiredAt)

Here I'm getting

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'e', "eyJhbGciOi"... is not valid JSON

And If I try to create a token verify function & call it to middleware than it show

> Server Error: The edge runtime does not support Node.js 'crypto' module.

```js
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { isTokenExpires } from "./app/_utils/getDataOfToken";

export function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const path = req.nextUrl.pathname;
  const isAuth = ["/signin", "/signup"];
  const isProtected = ["/profile", "/admin", "/sales", "/cart"];

  const token = req.cookies.get("token")?.value;

  if (isProtected.includes(path) && (!token || isTokenExpires(token))) {
    const response = NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/signin", req.url));
    return response;
  }
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/", "/signup", "/signin", "/profile", "/admin", "/sales", "/cart"],
};
```

How can I verify the token in middleware?

Comment: It seems like you have multiple problems here.  May I suggest you focus on one problem only in this question?  EG the token parsing, OR the `crypto` question, OR the question of how to verify a token in middleware?  Seems like you might be able to eliminate the first couple with a little searching, and focus on the last?